# LINQ & Many to Many Relationships

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, many-to-many

So I'm writing a "dynamic" Linq query. I've created an "options" class that holds all of the dynamic options that can be a part of the query. Some of these option properties are List objects, which hold IDs of entities that I want to return that are part of many-to-many relationships in SQL Server. A quick code example and descriptions of the tables might help (seriously pared down for brevity).

**Table Cars:**
    Id int PK,
    Model varchar(50),
    Year int

**Table Colors:**
    Id int PK,
    Name varchar(50)

**Table CarsXColors:**
    CarId int PK,
    ColorId int PK

```
public IEnumerable<Car> Search(SearchOptions options)
{
    var query = from car in ctx.Cars select car;

    // This works just fine
    if (options.MaxMileage.HasValue) query = query.Where(x => x.Mileage <= options.Mileage.Value);

    // How do I implement this pseudo code. options.Colors is a List<int>
    if (options.Colors.Count > 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(  -- select cars that are in the List<int> of colors --);
    }


    return query;
}
```

Comment: It's in the comments for the code, if you'd read it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying such an obvious fact (not)

Comment: You're welcome. Always happy to help those that have trouble keeping up. :)

Comment: I'm always happy to help the challenged of every kind :)

Comment: @Scott, I think @Carnotaurus is right -- the question-in-comment is quite difficult to notice.  Probably should put the question outside in the body text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you already got the answer, but also consider this alternative:

```
var query = 
    from car in ctx.Cars 
    where options.Colors.Count <= 0 || car.CarsXColors.Any(y => options.Colors.Contains(y.Id))
    select car;
```

This style is quite common as it generates the same SQL statement throughout so that database engines or LINQ can actually cache the query and/or query plan for faster response.

The database query optimizer will automatically eliminate the WHERE clause if options.Colors is empty, so you are not paying any performance penalties here.

Comment: Accepted for the explanation and so I don't have to accept my own answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
   query = query.Where(x => options.Colors.Contains(x.ColorID))
```

Comment: ColorId doens't exist in that entity. It's in a lookup table (i.e. many-to-many). There is no singular ColorId property.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question...

```
if (options.Colors.Count > 0) 
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.CarsXColors.Any(y => options.Colors.Contains(x.Id)));
}
```

Comment: Probably should be `Contains(y.Id)`